# Batch file to install downloaded windows patch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have downloaded to multiple windows patch file (File format .msu). I had tried with below batch file. But its not installing.

```
@echo off
cd/
wusa.exe C:\ kb000000.msu /quiet /norestart
echo " kb000000 is installed, processing the next one"
echo "****"
echo "This will take 5-10 mins for installing"
echo "****"
echo "All the patches are installed & Your system is about to restart now"
```

Comment: What error messages are you receiving? Try removing the `/quiet` switch and see whether the process generates error messages

Comment: You seem to be doing something dangerous: you have a command, which seems to work on one computer, so you decide to launch it as a batchfile on whatever other computer, and in top of that you prefer everything to happen in background. I would advise you to add the `/log` switch in order to see the results of the command. In case it doesn't work, the content of the logfile might give you some insights.